# The range(subnets) of VPC Endpoint affects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am trying to make the `S3 VPC Endpoint`.

In `VPC Endpoint` setting, it has `Subnets`

If I set the `S3 VPC Endpoint` with `Subnets`, only servers in these Subnet are affected?

If so, the case I don't set Subnets, whole nodes in EC2s　are affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I set the S3 VPC Endpoint with Subnets, only servers in these Subnet are affected?

Yes that is correct.

> If so, the case I don't set Subnets, whole nodes in EC2s　are affected?

If you don't add the S3 VPC Endpoint to any subnets, then **nothing** is affected.

Comment: Thank you very much !  In this VPC there is legacy S3 endpoint(Gateway) which has routetables. Target `Subnets` dosen't use these routetable , so I want to make another S3 endpoint for this target subnets only.